# Python: sklearn kFold return multiple values for keyword argument 'shuffle'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to perform cross validation with classic `kfold` using `sklearn`

```
def train_and_evaluate(clf, X_train, y_train):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # create a k-fold cross validation iterator of k=5 folds
    cv = KFold(int(X_train.shape[0]), 4, shuffle = True)  ## Classic KFold
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=cv)
    return (clf, scores) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
scaler  = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test  = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
clf1, scores1 = train_and_evaluate(linear_model.SGDRegressor(), X_train, y_train)

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'shuffle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature for KFold looks like this

```
sklearn.model_selection.KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
```

so when you pass those two positional arguments `(int(X_train.shape[0]), 4)` you are passing 4 for the argument `shuffle`. You then pass `shuffle` by name as well, so that's how you get the multiple arguments error.

I'm not super clear on why you are passing these two positional arguments, but I think if you want a 4 fold split, you only need to pass 4

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(100)

from  sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf=KFold(5,shuffle=True,random_state=None)

x=kf.split(X)

for i,j in x:

    print(i,j)
```